# shell - multiple text insertion into each line of a file

Tags: unix, shell, sed, cat

I have a text containing coordinates of points such as `x`, `y` and `z`, I would like to change each line to be like:

```
Point{ (1000+linenumber) } = {x , y, z};
```

What I want is: for example for line `212` which is:

```
-0.534 2.345 0
```

I want:

```
Point{1212} = {-0.534, 2.345, 0};
```

I tried this way (seems stupid to me) and still **NOT** complete:

```
while read p; do
  echo "$p"  | sed 's/\s/,/g;s/,$//' >> ./allPoint2
done <allPoint

rm -rf ./allPoint;
mv ./allPoint2 ./allPoint

cat -n allPoint > allPoint2
sed 's/^/Ponit{ /' ./allPoint2 >> allPoint3

rm -rf ./allPoint ./allPoint2;
mv ./allPoint3 ./allPoint

sed 's/$/}/' ./allPoint >> allPoint2

rm -rf ./allPoint;
mv ./allPoint2 ./allPoint
```

This is what I got: for example for line `212` the result here is:

```
Ponit{     212   -0.534, 2.345, 0}
```

Comment: Please clarify what the lines look like now and exactly how you want them to look afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple with `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "Point{%d} = {%s, %s, %s};\n", NR+1000,$1,$2,$3}' file
```

- `printf` format the output as desired.
- `NR+1000` is the line number inside the file +1000.
- `$1,$2,$3` are the fields 1 to 3.

Comment: This is a much cleaner and simpler solution than mine, awk is a better tool for the job than sed.

Comment: @Jack If you want to calculate, awk is better than sed.

Answer (score 0):

You're indeed correct that creating so many files is unnecessary, sed can be run in a chain, there is no need to save every step.

The following is a single line solution:

```
linenumber=0 && while read line; do linenumber=$((linenumber+1)) && echo $line | sed "s#^#Point{$linenumber} = {#g" | sed 's#$#};#g' >> out.txt; done<in.txt
```

Replace in.txt with your current text file, out.txt will be the result.